# How to translate Taxonomies in a PO file and PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, po

I am trying to translate a theme with PO and MO files and so far I managed to do it to the home page, but now I am trying to create a translation to all taxonomies but they have a different format and I don't know how to edit them.

This is the code I need to translate:

```
$ptlabels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Property Type', 'taxonomy general name', 'contempo' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Property Type', 'taxonomy singular name', 'contempo' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Property Types', 'contempo' ),
    'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Property Types', 'contempo' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Property Types', 'contempo' ),
    'parent_item' => null,
    'parent_item_colon' => null,
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Property Type', 'contempo' ),
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Property Type', 'contempo' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Property Type', 'contempo' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Property Type Name', 'contempo' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Property Types with commas', 'contempo' ),
    'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove Property Types', 'contempo' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used Property Types', 'contempo' )
);
```

I need to be able to translate `'Property Type'` , `'Search Property Types'` and so on...

I managed to translate other files by doing the following:

```
<label for="ct_price_from"><?php _e('Price From', 'contempo'); ?> (<?php currency(); ?>)</label>
```

and then adding a line to my PO file:

```
#: includes/advanced-search.php:99
msgid "Price From"
msgstr "Valor Inicial"
```

I hope someone can bring some light to my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) ? It makes the translation faster and more reliable...

Comment: I am, but that is not the issue. I don't know how to make the lines above editable for poedit